# How to edit an array's key?

Tags: php, arrays

Is it possible to edit the key once it has been made?

I know you can create an array with a different key but I couldn't see anything on the php site about editing the key latter.

Original array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => first
    [1] => color
)
```

What I would like:

```
Array
(
    [newName] => first
    [1] => color
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to change the key of an item, you must either set the value with the new key and `unset()` the old one (this technique changes the order of the array):

```
$arr['newName'] = $arr[0];
unset($arr[0]);
```

or use a wrapper that forgoes looping and allows you to modify the keys, as such:

```
function array_change_key(&$array, $search, $replace) {
    $keys = array_keys($array);
    $values = array_values($array);

    // Return FALSE if replace key already exists
    if(array_search($replace, $keys) !== FALSE) return FALSE;

    // Return FALSE if search key doesn't exists
    $searchKey = array_search($search, $keys); 
    if($searchKey === FALSE) return FALSE;

    $keys[$searchKey] = $replace;
    $array = array_combine($keys, $values);

    return TRUE; // Swap complete
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternate, simple approach, which is probably fairly efficient, as long as you do all of your re-keying for each array in a single call:

```
<?php
function mapKeys(array $arr, array $map) {
  //we'll build our new, rekeyed array here:
  $newArray = array();
  //iterate through the source array
  foreach($arr as $oldKey => $value) {
    //if the old key has been mapped to a new key, use the new one.  
    //Otherwise keep the old key
    $newKey = isset($map[$key]) ? $map[$key] : $oldKey;
    //add the value to the new array with the "new" key
    $newArray[$newKey] = $value;
  }
  return $newArray;
}

$arr = array('first', 'color');
$map = array(0 => 'newName');

print_r(mapKeys($arr, $map));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = array('foo', 'bar');

$array['newName'] = $array[0];
unset($array[0]);
```

That's pretty much the only thing you can do.

Comment: That changes the order of the array.